XML Script running to print the required output
I have an sample XML input file with the following contents:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<infobases>
  <infobase author="Chartered Professional Accountants of Canada" levelDefOrder="Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4,Level 5,Level 6,Level 7,Level 8,Level 9,Level 10,Level 11,Level 12,Level 13,Normal Level" levels="Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4,Level 5,Level 6,Level 7,Level 8,Level 9,Level 10,Level 11,Level 12,Level 13" name="info_a" title="CPA Canada Standards and Guidance Collection">
    <file level="Level 1" heading="XYZ1-L1">XYZ1-L1
      <file level="Level 2" heading="XYZ1-L12">XYZ1-L12
        <file level="Level 3" heading="XYZ1-L123">XYZ1-L123</file>
        <file level="Level 3" heading="XYZ1-L123">XYZ1-L123</file>
        <file level="Level 3" heading="XYZ1-L123">XYZ1-L123</file>
      </file>
    </file>
    <file level="Level 1" heading="XYZ2-L1">XYZ2-L1</file>
    <file level="Level 1" heading="XYZ2-L1">XYZ2-L1
      <file level="Level 2" heading="XYZ2-L12">XYZ2-L12</file>
      <file level="Level 2" heading="XYZ2-L123">XYZ2-L123
        <file level="Level 3" heading="XYZ1-L123">XYZ1-L123
          <file level="Level 4" heading="XYZ1-L123">XYZ1-L123</file>
        </file>
      </file>
    </file>
  </infobase>
</infobases>

I want to write a script to identify the file elements level attribute and give proper indentation while printing the headings of the file element . The file element heading will get a .ditamap extension which has other file elements as child and ignore other child elements(not here in the sample xml file). If a file element has no child file element then it gets a .dita extension added.
I have written a script in javascript which tends to do the proper indentation but the extension assigned is not proper. I am getting .dita for all file element heading. Here is code :
const fs = require('fs');
const XmlStream = require('xml-stream');

// Create a readable stream from the XML file
const stream = fs.createReadStream('input1.xml');

// Create a writable stream to the output text file
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

// Create a new XML stream parser
const xmlParser = new XmlStream(stream);

// Function to print headings with proper indentation
function printHeadingsToFile(file, indentation = '') {
    // Calculate the indentation based on the level of the file
    const levelIndentation = '    '.repeat(parseInt(file.$.level.substr(6)) - 1);

        // Determine file extension based on child elements
        const fileExtension = file.file ? 'ditamap' : 'dita';
    
    // Write the heading with indentation to the output file
    outputStream.write(`${indentation}${levelIndentation}${file.$.heading}.${fileExtension}\n`);

    // Check if there are nested files
    if (file.file) {
        // If nested files exist, recursively print their headings with increased indentation
        file.file.forEach(nestedFile => {
            printHeadingsToFile(nestedFile, `${indentation}${levelIndentation}`);
        });
    }
}


// Event listener for when a new XML element is encountered
xmlParser.on('startElement: file', function(element) {
    // Print headings for each file
    printHeadingsToFile(element);
});

// Event listener for when the parsing ends
xmlParser.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Parsing finished.');
    // Close the output stream after finishing writing
    outputStream.end();
});

// Event listener for any errors during parsing
xmlParser.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Error during parsing:', err);
    // Close the output stream if there is an error
    outputStream.end();
});


The output I am getting here is as follows:
XYZ1-L1.dita
    XYZ1-L12.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
XYZ2-L1.dita
XYZ2-L1.dita
    XYZ2-L12.dita
    XYZ2-L123.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
            XYZ1-L123.dita

Expected output:
XYZ1-L1.ditamap
    XYZ1-L12.ditamap
        XYZ1-L123.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
        XYZ1-L123.dita
XYZ2-L1.dita
XYZ2-L1.ditamap
    XYZ2-L12.dita
    XYZ2-L123.ditamap
        XYZ1-L123.ditamap
            XYZ1-L123.dita


why do you think an element with file as a child element would have an attribute called .file

you need to check to see if file has a child element called file instead - not sure how to do that in nodejs - probably complicated more by the xml-stream perhaps not yet parsing the child elements when the startElement: file event is emitted

A python script would be fine by me too @JaromandaX

then off you go and write one

Found a solution using a different xml parser package.
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require('sax');

// Create a SAX parser
const parser = sax.parser(true);

// Create a write stream to a text file
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

// Array to store file attributes
let fileAttributes = [];

// Event handlers for the SAX parser
parser.onopentag = function (node) {
    // Check if the current node is a <file> element
    if (node.name === 'file') {
        // Extract attributes and push them to the array
        fileAttributes.push(node.attributes);
    }
};

parser.onend = function () {
    // Parsing ends, log the final output
    //console.log('File attributes:', fileAttributes);
    // Function to determine the file extension
function getFileExtension(currentLevel, nextLevel) {
    if (currentLevel < nextLevel) {
        return '.ditamap';
    } else {
        return '.dita';
    }
}

// Iterate through the fileAttributes array
for (let i = 0; i < fileAttributes.length; i++) {
    const currentFile = fileAttributes[i];
    const nextFile = fileAttributes[i + 1];

    // Get the level numbers
    const currentLevel = parseInt(currentFile.level.match(/\d+/)[0]);
    const nextLevel = nextFile ? parseInt(nextFile.level.match(/\d+/)[0]) : 0;

    // Get the file extension
    const extension = getFileExtension(currentLevel, nextLevel);

    // Indentation based on the level
    const indentation = ' '.repeat((currentLevel - 1) * 4);

    // Prepare the text to write
    const textToWrite = indentation + currentFile.heading + extension + '\n';

    // Write the text to the output stream
    outputStream.write(textToWrite);
}
// Close the output stream when done
outputStream.end();
};

// Read XML file
const xmlData = fs.readFileSync('input.xml', 'utf8');

// Parse XML data
parser.write(xmlData).close();


Resultant output :
L1.ditamap
    L2.ditamap
        L3.dita
        L3.dita
        L3.dita
L1.dita
L1.ditamap
    L2.dita
    L2.ditamap
        L3.ditamap
            L4.ditamap
                Level5Text.dita

